# Scrolling data in ListView

Tags: listview, flutter

I'm trying to create a ListView that automatically scrolls its lines. I used as a basis a routine available here at the Forum. My problem is that it is in the message "RenderBox was not laid out" (attached image).

The ListView worked fine until I included SingleChildScrollView.

Can someone help me?[image]

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('A Idade do Lobo'),
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: COLOR_MAIN,
      ),
      body: NotificationListener(
        onNotification: (notif) {
          if (notif is ScrollEndNotification && scrollOn) {
            Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
              _scroll();
            });
          }
          return true;
        },
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Center(
                child: new Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: _showScrollPickerDialog,
                      child: Text('Rolagem ${_scrollSpeed}'),
                    ),
                    new RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: _showTomPickerDialog,
                      child: Text('TOM ${_tom}'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              new Expanded(
                child: new ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: _songDetails.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return new Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                          child: new RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(children: [
                              new TextSpan(
                                text: '${_songDetails[index].line}',
                                style: _getStyle(
                                  _songDetails[index].type,
                                ),
                                recognizer: new TapGestureRecognizer()
                                  ..onTap = () {),

                              ),
                            ]),
                          ),
                        ), 
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please include the error message as text instead of an image, that way it shows in the search engine and other members can copy it if needed. Also, there is [Stackoverflow in Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) should you be interested.

Comment: I believe this is an infinite unbounded size problem, because you are nesting expanded (and a listview) inside a listview (which needs explicit size given to it from its children) without shrinkwrapping.